# RAID6 failed instantly and switched to RAID0 - any chance to rescue?

Tags: linux, lvm, mdadm, raid6

I´m running a server ob Ubuntu 16.04. Data storage on this system uses a lvm on top of a software raid 6 whereas the os is installed on a separate raid 1 with lvm.
The raid 6 is built up of 7 partitions on 7 disks. 
After a raising amount of s.m.a.r.t errors on one of these disks, i decided to swap this disk to a new one before the array becomes degraded.

I did a `sudo mdadm /dev/md2 --fail /dev/sdd4`, follwed by `sudo mdadm /dev/md2 --remove /dev/sdd4` before i swapped the disks.
After the next startup everything seemed to be okay so i started partitioning the new disk. I did a `sudo parted --list` to adapt the partitioning of the other disks.

At this moment a strange problem occured and parted had problems accessing one of the old disk. I noticed that another drive has gone from the array and some seconds later another one. The array failed. I was shocked and shut the system down to prevent further errors.

Later i tried to start the system again and had strange failures like these:

```
ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
ata2: SError: { CommWake DevExch }
```

I only had a emergency console at this time so i started a live linux to further inspect the problem. I´ve read that i could securely do a `mdadm --assemble --scan` to try to fix the array but it remains in a curious state so i only removed the array from `mdadm.conf` and `fstab`.

The raid is now shown as a raid0 with 7 spare drives but the drives seem to be running okay the last hours in the remaining RAID1.

I´m unsure what i should do right now and i expect loosing all the data but i´m also hoping that there is a chance to rescue at least a part of the data. I have a backup but only a part because it was a 19TB array.

## State before swapping the disks

```
chris@uranus:~$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Thu Aug  6 00:45:41 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 18723832320 (17856.44 GiB 19173.20 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3744766464 (3571.29 GiB 3834.64 GB)
   Raid Devices : 7
  Total Devices : 7
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Fri Jul 13 17:39:04 2018
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 7
Working Devices : 7
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

     Layout : left-symmetric
 Chunk Size : 512K

       Name : uranus:2  (local to host uranus)
       UUID : 607914eb:666e2a46:b2e43557:02cc2983
     Events : 2738806

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8       20        0      active sync   /dev/sdb4
   1       8       36        1      active sync   /dev/sdc4
   2       8       52        2      active sync   /dev/sdd4
   6       8        1        3      active sync   /dev/sda1
   5       8       68        4      active sync   /dev/sde4
   8       8       97        5      active sync   /dev/sdg1
   7       8       81        6      active sync   /dev/sdf1
```

## Actual state

```
chris@uranus:/$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
      Version : 1.2
   Raid Level : raid0
Total Devices : 6
  Persistence : Superblock is persistent

        State : inactive

         Name : uranus:2  (local to host uranus)
         UUID : 607914eb:666e2a46:b2e43557:02cc2983
       Events : 2739360

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

   -       8        1        -        /dev/sda1
   -       8       20        -        /dev/sdb4
   -       8       36        -        /dev/sdc4
   -       8       68        -        /dev/sde4
   -       8       81        -        /dev/sdf1
   -       8       97        -        /dev/sdg1
```

## To clarify things

6 drives are not faulty, the 7th one had errors but i switched it to a new one. After the switch of this one faulty drive, smart data is good for all drives. There are no errors, no bad blocks, no pending, uncorrectable or reallocated sectors.

My last `--detail` shows only 6 drives because i did not added the new drive to the existing array.

The raid 1 the os relies on, was basically on 3 + 1 spare of the same 7 disks but on own partitions. As i remove /dev/sdd, the spare drive tooked it´s place so it consists now of 3 partitions without a spare.
There are also boot partitions on 3 of these disks and swap partitions in a raid 1 on 2 of these disks.

The problem is, that mdadm shows this array now as a raid 0 with 7 spares as `cat /proc/mdstat` shows and i have to get it to it´s original raid6 config with 6 out of 7 drives in its degraded state. There seems to be a problem with the config but i didn´t changed anything in this. After and only if i could restore the array, i would add the switched 7th partition back to the array to get my original 7th drive raid6.

If i read the manpage right, `mdadm --assemble --scan` restores array information based on the config or `/proc/mdstat` but these seem to be already wrong.

## Some more outputs

`cat /proc/mdstat` - Now

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md2 : inactive sdg1[8](S) sdf1[7](S) sdb4[0](S) sda1[6](S) sde4[5](S) sdc4[1](S)
      22468633600 blocks super 1.2

md129 : active raid1 sdb3[0] sde3[4] sdc3[1]
      146353024 blocks super 1.2 [3/3] [UUU]

md128 : active raid1 sdb2[0] sde2[4](S) sdc2[1]
      15616896 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

`cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` - Now

```
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays

ARRAY /dev/md128 metadata=1.2 UUID=6813258b:250929d6:8a1e9d34:422a9fbd name=uranus:128
   spares=1
ARRAY /dev/md129 metadata=1.2 UUID=ab06d13f:a70de5a6:c83a9383:b1beb84c name=uranus:129
ARRAY /dev/md2 metadata=1.2 UUID=607914eb:666e2a46:b2e43557:02cc2983 name=uranus:2

# This file was auto-generated on Mon, 10 Aug 2015 18:09:47 +0200
# by mkconf $Id$
#ARRAY /dev/md/128 metadata=1.2 UUID=6813258b:250929d6:8a1e9d34:422a9fbd name=uranus:128
#   spares=2
#ARRAY /dev/md/129 metadata=1.2 UUID=ab06d13f:a70de5a6:c83a9383:b1beb84c name=uranus:129
#   spares=1
#ARRAY /dev/md/2 metadata=1.2 UUID=607914eb:666e2a46:b2e43557:02cc2983 name=uranus:2
```

`cat /etc/fstab` - Now

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/vgSystem-vRoot /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/md128 during installation
UUID=5a5b997d-9e94-4391-955f-a2b9a3f63820 none            swap    sw              0       0
#/dev/vgData/vData      /srv    ext4    defaults        0       0
#10.10.0.15:/srv/BackupsUranusAutomatic/data    /mnt/mars/uranus/automatic/data nfs     clientaddr=10.10.0.10,vers=4,noatime,addr=10.10.0.15,noauto     0       0
#10.10.0.15:/srv/BackupsUranusAutomatic/media   /mnt/mars/uranus/automatic/media        nfs     clientaddr=10.10.0.10,vers=4,noatime,addr=10.10.0.15,noauto     0       0
#/srv/shares/Videos/Ungesichert/Videorecorder   /srv/vdr/video  bind    bind    0       0
#/dev/sdh1      /mnt/usbdisk    ntfs    noatime,noauto  0       0
```

Disks and partitions - Before the problem occured

```
Medium /dev/sda: 3,7 TiB, 4000787030016 Bytes, 7814037168 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
Typ der Medienbezeichnung: gpt
Medienkennung: 98C35BD3-BFBC-4A4B-AEC9-6D4AFB775AF4

Gerät           Start       Ende   Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/sda1        2048 7489808383 7489806336   3,5T Linux RAID
/dev/sda2  7489808384 7791525887  301717504 143,9G Linux RAID


Medium /dev/sdb: 3,7 TiB, 4000787030016 Bytes, 7814037168 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
Typ der Medienbezeichnung: gpt
Medienkennung: 49102EF7-9FA2-4990-8C30-6C5B463B917E

Gerät          Start       Ende   Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/sdb1       2048      20479      18432     9M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2      20480   31270911   31250432  14,9G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb3   31270912  324239359  292968448 139,7G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb4  324239360 7814035455 7489796096   3,5T Linux RAID



Medium /dev/sdc: 3,7 TiB, 4000787030016 Bytes, 7814037168 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
Typ der Medienbezeichnung: gpt
Medienkennung: 6A037D00-F252-4CA0-8D68-430734BCA765

Gerät          Start       Ende   Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/sdc1       2048      20479      18432     9M BIOS boot
/dev/sdc2      20480   31270911   31250432  14,9G Linux RAID
/dev/sdc3   31270912  324239359  292968448 139,7G Linux RAID
/dev/sdc4  324239360 7814035455 7489796096   3,5T Linux RAID


Medium /dev/sdd: 3,7 TiB, 4000787030016 Bytes, 7814037168 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
Typ der Medienbezeichnung: gpt
Medienkennung: EADC29D6-C2E9-4AC8-B1B2-F01A5233467C

Gerät          Start       Ende   Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/sdd1       2048      20479      18432     9M BIOS boot
/dev/sdd2      20480   31270911   31250432  14,9G Linux RAID
/dev/sdd3   31270912  324239359  292968448 139,7G Linux RAID
/dev/sdd4  324239360 7814035455 7489796096   3,5T Linux RAID


Medium /dev/sde: 3,7 TiB, 4000787030016 Bytes, 7814037168 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
Typ der Medienbezeichnung: gpt
Medienkennung: 3D7EBBFD-C00D-4503-8BF1-A71534F643E1

Gerät          Start       Ende   Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/sde1       2048      20479      18432     9M Linux filesystem
/dev/sde2      20480   31270911   31250432  14,9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sde3   31270912  324239359  292968448 139,7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sde4  324239360 7814035455 7489796096   3,5T Linux filesystem


Medium /dev/sdf: 3,7 TiB, 4000787030016 Bytes, 7814037168 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
Typ der Medienbezeichnung: gpt
Medienkennung: FCA42FC2-C5E9-45B6-9C18-F103C552993D

Gerät           Start       Ende   Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/sdf1        2048 7489824767 7489822720   3,5T Linux RAID
/dev/sdf2  7489824768 7791525887  301701120 143,9G Linux RAID


Medium /dev/sdg: 3,7 TiB, 4000787030016 Bytes, 7814037168 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
Typ der Medienbezeichnung: gpt
Medienkennung: 8FF8C4CC-6788-47D7-8264-8FA6EF912555

Gerät           Start       Ende   Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/sdg1        2048 7489824767 7489822720   3,5T Linux RAID
/dev/sdg2  7489824768 7791525887  301701120 143,9G Linux RAID


Medium /dev/md2: 17,4 TiB, 19173204295680 Bytes, 37447664640 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 524288 Bytes / 2621440 Bytes


Medium /dev/md128: 14,9 GiB, 15991701504 Bytes, 31233792 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes


Medium /dev/md129: 139,6 GiB, 149865496576 Bytes, 292706048 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes


Medium /dev/mapper/vgSystem-vRoot: 74,5 GiB, 79997960192 Bytes, 156246016 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes


Medium /dev/mapper/vgData-vData: 17,4 TiB, 19173199577088 Bytes, 37447655424 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 524288 Bytes / 2621440 Bytes


Medium /dev/mapper/vgSystem-testBtrfs: 5 GiB, 5368709120 Bytes, 10485760 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
```

Disks, partitions, raid devices and volumes - Before the problem occured

```
NAME                     UUID                                   FSTYPE            MOUNTPOINT LABEL        SIZE
sda                                                                                                       3,7T
├─sda1                   607914eb-666e-2a46-b2e4-355702cc2983   linux_raid_member            uranus:2     3,5T
│ └─md2                  OTNyDe-fNAP-aLzy-Uwat-yYVH-E11D-d1LyzH LVM2_member                              17,4T
│   └─vgData-vData       a9b3d18d-e45f-4d0f-ab3d-9fe8bfa42157   ext4              /srv       data        17,4T
└─sda2                                                                                                  143,9G
sdb                                                                                                       3,7T
├─sdb1                                                                                                      9M
├─sdb2                   6813258b-2509-29d6-8a1e-9d34422a9fbd   linux_raid_member            uranus:128  14,9G
│ └─md128                5a5b997d-9e94-4391-955f-a2b9a3f63820   swap              [SWAP]                 14,9G
├─sdb3                   ab06d13f-a70d-e5a6-c83a-9383b1beb84c   linux_raid_member            uranus:129 139,7G
│ └─md129                7QXSVM-dauj-RUQ1-uoQp-IamT-TTZo-slzArT LVM2_member                             139,6G
│   ├─vgSystem-vRoot     fb4bfbb3-de6c-47ef-b237-27af04fa2f4c   ext4              /          root        74,5G
│   └─vgSystem-testBtrfs 27bbab4c-3c9f-4743-83ac-61e8b41f2bd3   btrfs                                       5G
└─sdb4                   607914eb-666e-2a46-b2e4-355702cc2983   linux_raid_member            uranus:2     3,5T
  └─md2                  OTNyDe-fNAP-aLzy-Uwat-yYVH-E11D-d1LyzH LVM2_member                              17,4T
    └─vgData-vData       a9b3d18d-e45f-4d0f-ab3d-9fe8bfa42157   ext4              /srv       data        17,4T
sdc                                                                                                       3,7T
├─sdc1                                                                                                      9M
├─sdc2                   6813258b-2509-29d6-8a1e-9d34422a9fbd   linux_raid_member            uranus:128  14,9G
│ └─md128                5a5b997d-9e94-4391-955f-a2b9a3f63820   swap              [SWAP]                 14,9G
├─sdc3                   ab06d13f-a70d-e5a6-c83a-9383b1beb84c   linux_raid_member            uranus:129 139,7G
│ └─md129                7QXSVM-dauj-RUQ1-uoQp-IamT-TTZo-slzArT LVM2_member                             139,6G
│   ├─vgSystem-vRoot     fb4bfbb3-de6c-47ef-b237-27af04fa2f4c   ext4              /          root        74,5G
│   └─vgSystem-testBtrfs 27bbab4c-3c9f-4743-83ac-61e8b41f2bd3   btrfs                                       5G
└─sdc4                   607914eb-666e-2a46-b2e4-355702cc2983   linux_raid_member            uranus:2     3,5T
  └─md2                  OTNyDe-fNAP-aLzy-Uwat-yYVH-E11D-d1LyzH LVM2_member                              17,4T
    └─vgData-vData       a9b3d18d-e45f-4d0f-ab3d-9fe8bfa42157   ext4              /srv       data        17,4T
sdd                                                                                                       3,7T
├─sdd1                                                                                                      9M
├─sdd2                   6813258b-2509-29d6-8a1e-9d34422a9fbd   linux_raid_member            uranus:128  14,9G
│ └─md128                5a5b997d-9e94-4391-955f-a2b9a3f63820   swap              [SWAP]                 14,9G
├─sdd3                   ab06d13f-a70d-e5a6-c83a-9383b1beb84c   linux_raid_member            uranus:129 139,7G
│ └─md129                7QXSVM-dauj-RUQ1-uoQp-IamT-TTZo-slzArT LVM2_member                             139,6G
│   ├─vgSystem-vRoot     fb4bfbb3-de6c-47ef-b237-27af04fa2f4c   ext4              /          root        74,5G
│   └─vgSystem-testBtrfs 27bbab4c-3c9f-4743-83ac-61e8b41f2bd3   btrfs                                       5G
└─sdd4                   607914eb-666e-2a46-b2e4-355702cc2983   linux_raid_member            uranus:2     3,5T
  └─md2                  OTNyDe-fNAP-aLzy-Uwat-yYVH-E11D-d1LyzH LVM2_member                              17,4T
    └─vgData-vData       a9b3d18d-e45f-4d0f-ab3d-9fe8bfa42157   ext4              /srv       data        17,4T
sde                                                                                                       3,7T
├─sde1                                                                                                      9M
├─sde2                   6813258b-2509-29d6-8a1e-9d34422a9fbd   linux_raid_member            uranus:128  14,9G
│ └─md128                5a5b997d-9e94-4391-955f-a2b9a3f63820   swap              [SWAP]                 14,9G
├─sde3                   ab06d13f-a70d-e5a6-c83a-9383b1beb84c   linux_raid_member            uranus:129 139,7G
│ └─md129                7QXSVM-dauj-RUQ1-uoQp-IamT-TTZo-slzArT LVM2_member                             139,6G
│   ├─vgSystem-vRoot     fb4bfbb3-de6c-47ef-b237-27af04fa2f4c   ext4              /          root        74,5G
│   └─vgSystem-testBtrfs 27bbab4c-3c9f-4743-83ac-61e8b41f2bd3   btrfs                                       5G
└─sde4                   607914eb-666e-2a46-b2e4-355702cc2983   linux_raid_member            uranus:2     3,5T
  └─md2                  OTNyDe-fNAP-aLzy-Uwat-yYVH-E11D-d1LyzH LVM2_member                              17,4T
    └─vgData-vData       a9b3d18d-e45f-4d0f-ab3d-9fe8bfa42157   ext4              /srv       data        17,4T
sdf                                                                                                       3,7T
├─sdf1                   607914eb-666e-2a46-b2e4-355702cc2983   linux_raid_member            uranus:2     3,5T
│ └─md2                  OTNyDe-fNAP-aLzy-Uwat-yYVH-E11D-d1LyzH LVM2_member                              17,4T
│   └─vgData-vData       a9b3d18d-e45f-4d0f-ab3d-9fe8bfa42157   ext4              /srv       data        17,4T
└─sdf2                                                                                                  143,9G
sdg                                                                                                       3,7T
├─sdg1                   607914eb-666e-2a46-b2e4-355702cc2983   linux_raid_member            uranus:2     3,5T
│ └─md2                  OTNyDe-fNAP-aLzy-Uwat-yYVH-E11D-d1LyzH LVM2_member                              17,4T
│   └─vgData-vData       a9b3d18d-e45f-4d0f-ab3d-9fe8bfa42157   ext4              /srv       data        17,4T
└─sdg2
```

## Array Devices Superblocks

`mdadm --examine /dev/sd<array-member-harddrives>` - Now

There are only 6 drives because the 7th 'new' drive wasn´t added to the array yet.

```
chris@uranus:/$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sda1
[sudo] Passwort für chris:
/dev/sda1:   
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 607914eb:666e2a46:b2e43557:02cc2983
           Name : uranus:2  (local to host uranus)
  Creation Time : Thu Aug  6 00:45:41 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 7

 Avail Dev Size : 7489544192 (3571.29 GiB 3834.65 GB)
     Array Size : 18723832320 (17856.44 GiB 19173.20 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7489532928 (3571.29 GiB 3834.64 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=11264 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 49c6404e:ee9509ba:c980942a:1db9cf3c

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Fri Jul 13 22:34:48 2018
       Checksum : aae603a7 - correct
         Events : 2739360

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AA.AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

chris@uranus:/$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb4
/dev/sdb4:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 607914eb:666e2a46:b2e43557:02cc2983
           Name : uranus:2  (local to host uranus)
  Creation Time : Thu Aug  6 00:45:41 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 7

 Avail Dev Size : 7489533952 (3571.29 GiB 3834.64 GB)
     Array Size : 18723832320 (17856.44 GiB 19173.20 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7489532928 (3571.29 GiB 3834.64 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 61d97294:3ce7cd84:7bb4d5f1:d301c842

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Fri Jul 13 22:42:15 2018
       Checksum : 890fbe3d - correct
         Events : 2739385

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA..A.. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

chris@uranus:/$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdc4
/dev/sdc4:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 607914eb:666e2a46:b2e43557:02cc2983
           Name : uranus:2  (local to host uranus)
  Creation Time : Thu Aug  6 00:45:41 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 7

 Avail Dev Size : 7489533952 (3571.29 GiB 3834.64 GB)
     Array Size : 18723832320 (17856.44 GiB 19173.20 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7489532928 (3571.29 GiB 3834.64 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : ee70c4ab:5b65dae7:df3a78f0:e8bdcead

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Fri Jul 13 22:42:15 2018
       Checksum : 6d171664 - correct
         Events : 2739385

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA..A.. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

chris@uranus:/$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sde4
/dev/sde4:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 607914eb:666e2a46:b2e43557:02cc2983
           Name : uranus:2  (local to host uranus)
  Creation Time : Thu Aug  6 00:45:41 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 7

 Avail Dev Size : 7489533952 (3571.29 GiB 3834.64 GB)
     Array Size : 18723832320 (17856.44 GiB 19173.20 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7489532928 (3571.29 GiB 3834.64 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 6ce5311f:084ded8e:ba3d4e06:43e38c67

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Fri Jul 13 22:42:15 2018
       Checksum : 572b9ac7 - correct
         Events : 2739385

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 4
   Array State : AA..A.. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

chris@uranus:/$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdf1
/dev/sdf1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 607914eb:666e2a46:b2e43557:02cc2983
           Name : uranus:2  (local to host uranus)
  Creation Time : Thu Aug  6 00:45:41 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 7

 Avail Dev Size : 7489560576 (3571.30 GiB 3834.66 GB)
     Array Size : 18723832320 (17856.44 GiB 19173.20 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7489532928 (3571.29 GiB 3834.64 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=27648 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 7c4fbe19:d63eced4:1b40cf79:e759fe4b

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Fri Jul 13 22:36:17 2018
       Checksum : ef93d641 - correct
         Events : 2739381

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 6
   Array State : AA..A.A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

chris@uranus:/$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdg1
/dev/sdg1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 607914eb:666e2a46:b2e43557:02cc2983
           Name : uranus:2  (local to host uranus)
  Creation Time : Thu Aug  6 00:45:41 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 7

 Avail Dev Size : 7489560576 (3571.30 GiB 3834.66 GB)
     Array Size : 18723832320 (17856.44 GiB 19173.20 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7489532928 (3571.29 GiB 3834.64 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=27648 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 36d9dffc:27699128:e84f87e7:38960357

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Fri Jul 13 22:35:47 2018
       Checksum : 9f34d651 - correct
         Events : 2739377

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 5
   Array State : AA..AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Answer (score 3):

You had one drive down (the one you were replacing) when this happened:

> At this moment a strange problem occured and parted had problems
>   accessing one of the old disk. I noticed that another drive has gone
>   from the array and some seconds later another one. The array failed. I
>   was shocked and shut the system down to prevent further errors.

That makes for 3 drives if the fails were fatal.

You stated that the OS was on a RAID 1, I assume those were 2 disks, and the other 7 disks were on the RAID 6.

RAID 6 can withstand the loss of two disks in the array. If you had 3 failures on the RAID 6 array (assuming none of the failed disks were from the RAID 1), and if the disks are not in a good state, then most likely the data is lost.

You could verify the state of each disk with:

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdX
```

And then you can find if the 3 disks are out or if it was a fluke. **If it was a fluke, and you  are sure everything is Ok**, that your mdadm.conf and fstab are  correct, as your array seems to be *inactive*, then you could try to force a re-assemble with (**warning: dangerous, read disclaimer below**):

```
sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md2
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan --force
```

Note: On your last `--detail` the output shows 6 disks, not 7. `/dev/sdd` is missing it seems.

You could paste your **mdadm.conf**, **fstab** and LVM VG, LV and partitions to help understand the configuration.

**Disclaimer**: Trying stuff with a broken RAID is dangerous, I'm recommending steps based on the available information you provided, I can't guarantee it will work or that it won't destroy your data. Run under your own responsibility and at your own risk.

Comment: One safe-guard could be to copy image copies from failed drives to similar drives, and then work on the original ones trying to fix RAID. This way one could try different things. Naturally one needs corresponding new hard drives.

Comment: I´ve updated my question with new information to clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

mdadm uses `superblocks` to determine how to assemble disks and so on.
In such case it is always very helpful and informative to look at the actual superblock data of a physical drive **before** doing **any** actions which **write** something to disks (eg. `mdadm --assemble --scan --force`, which will update mdadm superblocks).

Use `mdadm --examine /dev/sd<your-array-member-harddrives>` to see what the superblock contains.
It should give you an impression when something failed, how much offset you have between the disks in terms of writes, and much more.

After having a clear picture of what **is** the current state on the physical drives, you can come up with a strategy to fix things.

But first of all, I'd also consider that the mainboard/sata-controller/scsi-controller/... has a physical defect. So many disks failing within a very short period of time is unusual (except one had the great idea of using all disks from the same manufacturer, and production batch to build up the raid system), and could indicate that there is a controller problem.
Re-building/Re-syncing a damaged raid on a hard disk controller, which is eventually failing will only lead to disaster.

Comment: I´ve updated my question with devices superblock information. Maybe you can take another look. I´ve ordered a nas system for future usage but to try restoring the raid, i would like to go with the old system. If the controller fails while restoring, it´s okay.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just provide some ideas how/what to analyse to get an overview of the current state:

First section is, not very interesting and should be the same for all array members.

```
          Magic : a92b4efc               
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 607914eb:666e2a46:b2e43557:02cc2983
           Name : uranus:2  (local to host uranus)
  Creation Time : Thu Aug  6 00:45:41 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 7

 Avail Dev Size : 7489544192 (3571.29 GiB 3834.65 GB)
     Array Size : 18723832320 (17856.44 GiB 19173.20 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7489532928 (3571.29 GiB 3834.64 GB)
```

Still not really interesting, offsets may vary in case disks are not equally sized. The UUID is the hard drive UUID, and is unique for each drive.

```
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=11264 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 49c6404e:ee9509ba:c980942a:1db9cf3c

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
```

Here it starts to get interesting, comments starting with `#`:

```
    Update Time : Fri Jul 13 22:34:48 2018   # last write activity on the drive
       Checksum : aae603a7 - correct   # should be equal on all disks, when the state is clean
         Events : 2739360   # Events on the disk, in bock/chunk units

         Layout : left-symmetric   # could be relevant for rebuilding the array, left-symmetric is default for x86
     Chunk Size : 512K
```

Next section is interesting for rebuilding the array, especially when forming the command the `Device Role` is important.

```
   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AA.AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

The array state is just informative, but will not help a lot.

First of all we want to get an idea of `How far have disks run apart during the failure?`

If I recall correctly, there is a threshold of `50` events in mdadm code when trying to `assemble --force`. Which means, if we have a difference in events `>50` `assemble --force` will not work any more. Although having a difference of `<50` events will also not guarantee that forcing an assembly will work. In such a case, the only possibility is to re-create the array with exactly the same parameters as it is already, and instruct mdadm to `--create --assume-clean`. When one is in the "lucky" situation that all superblocks are available and can  be read, then this should be possible quite "easily" but care to be taken.

Event count looks like the first disk gone out first, then last, and then last but one. Difference is `<50`, it could eventually get pretty easy.

```
     Events : 2739360
     Events : 2739385
     Events : 2739385
     Events : 2739385
     Events : 2739381
     Events : 2739377
```

Properly interpreting the `Array State` is only possible with having an eye on the `Events` count & `Drive Role`.

```
Device Role : Active device 3
Device Role : Active device 0
Device Role : Active device 1
Device Role : Active device 4
Device Role : Active device 6
Device Role : Active device 5

Array State : AA.AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
Array State : AA..A.. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
Array State : AA..A.. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
Array State : AA..A.. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
Array State : AA..A.A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
Array State : AA..AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

`mdadm` starts counting at `0`. Drive `2` failed first, then drive `3`, later drive `5` and in the end on drive `6`.
Notice that drive `5` still lists drive `6` as active, as well as drive `3` lists `3`, `5` and `6` as active. So most likely the drives have not updated the superblock when another drive failed.

After seeing the `Array States`, I do assume that an automatic `assemble --force` will not play out well, as there is no consistency across 5 devices on the `Array State`. The array was `raid6` with 7 disks, so in this case we would need to have 5 disks that agree on the `Array State` and have less than 50 Events difference, which is not the case.

Remember, `mdadm`/`raid` is built to not loose data. So there are mechanisms in the code, that prevent `mdadm` from actions that could harm data. An automated reassembly, even with --force, will only trigger actions that will succeed very likely. If there is not enough/consistent information in the superblocks for mdadm to take a save decision, it will fail.
If you really know what you do, you can simply re-write the superblocks with `create --assume-clean` and all the information needed to set the raid back into operation. But this will be a manual task, where you as admin/user have to instruct the software what exactly to do.

I'm not going to provide a copy & paste command here, because I think it is essential in such a situation, that one knows what one does before executing a "repair-my-raid" command. And to deepen knowledge, reading the whole RAID Recovery related articles on the Linux RAID Wiki is essential, and my conclusion for this answer.

https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Linux_Raid#When_Things_Go_Wrogn
https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_Recovery
https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Recovering_a_failed_software_RAID

Comment: I´ve read the suggested raid recovery page and some linked pages there and on other sites. I´m not here to blame someone if the recovery fails but i need someone that has experience in recovering raids and guide me a little bit. It´s my responsibility if things get even worse. Thanks in advance. I have some remaining questions.

Comment: 1. Would you suggest first trying `--assemble --force`, maybe with an overlay file?

Comment: 2. If i use a `--create --assume-clean`, is it a better choice to create the last functioning setup with 6 disks or maybe a setup with only 5 drives that have the highest event count? Is this even possible? My goal is restoring some important data from the array and no permanent solution.

Comment: 3. I have details about the array before the crash occured. According to this i would come up with a `mdadm --create --assume-clean --level=6 --raid-devices=7 --size=3744766464 /dev/sdb4 /dev/sdc4 missing /dev/sda1 /dev/sde4 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdf1` for 6 drives, respectively `mdadm --create --assume-clean --level=6 --raid-devices=7 --size=3744766464 /dev/sdb4 /dev/sdc4 missing missing /dev/sde4 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdf1` on a 5 drive solution. Would you agree with this?

Answer (score 0):

`1. Would you suggest first trying --assemble --force, maybe with an overlay file?`

In my point of view this is definitely the first option to try. Using an overlay file or not, depends on your data and your risk-willingness. So far, I had in such situations backups and therefore didn't use the overlay option. If you want to be on the safe side, use it. There are a few points which I'd like to highlight in that area:

- Do not consider using mdadm `< 4.0` versions. Make a backport, or compile a version `>= 4.0`. There was some bug in `3.x` that had as a result failing `assemble --force` actions which did work nicely with `4.0`.
- When trying `assemble --force` use `--verbose` it will give you a good set of information which can be helpful for further steps and understanding what happened or what failed.

---

`2. If i use a --create --assume-clean, is it a better choice to create the last functioning setup with 6 disks or maybe a setup with only 5 drives that have the highest event count? The  Is this even possible? My goal is restoring some important data from the array and no permanent solution.`

In your case, where the Event-offset is this small, I think there is nothing wrong with recreating the array with 6/7 disks. If you suspect that the HBA (sata/ide/scsi controller) could have an issue it eventually should be considered to leave out suspected port(s). But that depends on the hardware and wiring. And yes, it would be possible, but is dependent on the raid-type. With raid6 you could try to re-build with 5/7 disks only, technically there should not be any limitation to do that. Important is only, if you re-create it with 5/7 there is definitely no more option for a drive to fail.

`3. I have details about the array before the crash occured. According to this i would come up with a mdadm --create --assume-clean --level=6 --raid-devices=7 --size=3744766464 /dev/sdb4 /dev/sdc4 missing /dev/sda1 /dev/sde4 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdf1 for 6 drives, respectively mdadm --create --assume-clean --level=6 --raid-devices=7 --size=3744766464 /dev/sdb4 /dev/sdc4 missing missing /dev/sde4 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdf1 on a 5 drive solution. Would you agree with this?`

I've not verified the details (drive order, size, missing positions, ...), but the commands look good. Still, as mentioned on the Linux Raid Wiki a recreation should be considered as **LAST** resort. When needing to do so, I always try to be as specific as possible. Just remember that I last  time looked over the mdadm man-page and added all options where I knew the data from the informations I had (e.g. even chunk-size, alignment, ...). There are a lot of defaults which one can omit, but when one is sure about the values, why not be specific.

---

What I'd try in your situation is the following:

- Bring `mdadm` up to a version of `>=4.0`
- Stop the array, in case it is running. Check `/proc/mdstat` and use `mdadm --stop ...`.
- Verify disk & HBA (sata/ide/scsi controler). Check `dmesg` and `smartctl` logs. Try to read from a disk, (eg. `dd if=/dev/hda1 of=/dev/null bs=1M count=2048`. Re-check `dmesg` and `smartctl` logs. Repeat that, add some `ibs=` and `skip=`. Re-check `dmesg` and `smartctl` logs. If you do see any `resets|timeouts|failures` on `ata|sata|scsi|...` HBA stop any procedures on the disk using that hardware.
- Repeat verify disks & HBA on all disks.
- Run `mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose`. This will most likely fail, but it will give you a good overview of what mdadm discovers and provide an idea what would happen when you `force` that.
- Study above output, check if what you see, matches the information you already gathered about your drives/arrays.
- Stop the array, in case it is running or was started.
- If you're happy with what mdadm would do on `--assemble --scan --verbose`, try to `--force` it.
- If all of that failed, make full disk backups (or create overlay files), and then go back to the road of **LAST** resort and re-create the whole array with assume-clean and all the informations you gathered from your array.